# PHP Mailer Class - Securing Email Credentials

Tags: security, email, phpmailer, credentials

I am using the php mailer class to send email via my scripts.

The structure is as follows:

$mail = new PHPMailer;

```
$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'myserver.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'info@somedomain.com';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'user123';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'pass123';
```

It seems to me to be a bit of a security hole having the mailbox credentials in plain view. So I thought I might put these in an external file outside of the web root. My question is how would I then assign the $mail object these values.

I of course no how to use `include` and/or `requires`... would it simple be a case of....

```
$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'myserver.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication

includes '../locationOutsideWebroot/emailCredntials.php';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'pass123';
```

Then emailCredentails.php:

```
<?php
$mail->Username = 'info@somedomain.com';
$mail->Password = 'user123';
?>
```

Would this be sufficient and secure enough?

Thanks,

Alan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that your credentials should be stored in a configuration file (INI or JSON) outside the webroot. Since the protocol requires the raw credentials, that is the most secure approach. Also, don't forget to set proper access permissions to the configuration file.

Small example:

```
<?php

$config = parse_ini_file('/var/app/config.ini', true);

// PHPMailer
$mail->Username = $config['email']['username'];
$mail->Password = $config['email']['password'];
```

Comment: Ah thanks that's a neat solution. What is the significance of using a .ini file rather than a .php?

Comment: It's common to store your application configuration information in external plain-text files. MySQL, Apache, you name it. Most applications have a INI file or even their own markup language for storing configuration. Although some PHP projects also store that in .php files with arrays, i find it easier for everyone involved to use a popular and easy to read format.

Comment: ok so it's just a preference or style, in terms of function and security it won't make any difference right? Many thanks...

Comment: No, because they're all plain text files. Just make sure you are storing in the right places with proper permissions.

Comment: I had mis-understood exactly what a .ini file is, after some research I can see that it has a specific structure. I now have it working and reading from a .ini file .... I quite literally have learned something new today!